# How to display ID for each form in Django Formset

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Need to make the UI more ordered, can i have indexing for the forms in formset or access the form ID?

```
                             <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div id="form-container">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        {{ formset1.management_form }}
                                        {% for form in formset1 %}
                                            <div class="test-form">
                                                {% crispy form %}
                                            </div>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        <button id="add-form" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Another Request
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: if formset1 is created with instances of model, simply in forloop add {{form.instance.id}}

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło model is not used here, its just fields

Comment: So any index I can think of is {{ forloop.counter }}

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use forloop.counter within your forloop like this, can assign the value to name or id

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
       <div id="form-container">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ formset1.management_form }}
          {% for form in formset1 %}
       {% crispy form %}
       </div>

{% endfor %}

    <button id="add-form" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Another Request </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```